# How to fix the error-log of undefined index which is a unknown variable

Tags: php

How to fix the error-log of undefined index which is a variable

I have array below:

```
$array = 
Array ( 
[A01] => Array ( [cat_no] => A01 [item] => Apple [supplier] => SAM [usd] => 30) 
[B01] => Array ( [cat_no] => B01 [item] => Banana [supplier] => TOM [usd] => 40)
[D01] => Array ( [cat_no] => D01 [item] => Durian [supplier] => SAM [usd] => 10)
[M01] => Array ( [cat_no] => M01 [item] => Mango [supplier] => TOM [usd] => 20)
[P01] => Array ( [cat_no] => P01 [item] => Pear [supplier] => BOB [usd] => 10))
```

the value of usd is a variable that will change from time to time.

I built associative array of supplier with total usd if item usd < 15:

```
foreach ($array as $item){

    if ($item['usd'] > 15) { $buy[$item['supplier']] += $item['usd']; } }

print_r($buy);
```

It does output what I want,

```
Array ( [SAM] => 30 [TOM] => 60 )
```

The problem is I get this in error log:

```
Undefined index: SAM in....
```

How can I fix this to make it clean...???

Comment: A: You give it a default empty value. Ternary operators are good to use also.

Comment: Is the array valid?  Aren't you missing a comma between SAM and TOM?

Comment: Assuming his array is correct because he is getting that far, @FunkFortyNiner is right he needs to assign a default value to `$buy[$item['supplier']]` simply adding `if(!isset($buy[$item['supplier']])){$buy[$item['supplier']] = 0;}` above the if statement would suffice.

Comment: You haven't shown all the code. You are using your `$buy` variable later on and referencing `$buy['SAM']` without checking if it really exists.

Comment: @Second2None I think your solution is what I need. At this moment it does kill the error log.

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign default array to **$buy** Variable and need to modified  assign value into buy array. check update code and try it. if you fetch issues then modify question or add comment.

```
<?php 
$array =  array( 
'A01' => array ('cat_no' => 'A01' ,'item' => 'Apple' ,'supplier' => 'SAM','usd' => '30'), 
'B01' => array ('cat_no'=> 'B01' ,'item' => 'Banana','supplier' => 'TOM','usd' => '40'),
'D01' => array ('cat_no'=> 'D01' ,'item' => 'Durian','supplier' => 'SAM','usd'=> '10'),
'M01' => array ('cat_no'=> 'M01','item' => 'Mango','supplier'=> 'TOM','usd'=> '20'),
'P01' => array ('cat_no'=> 'P01' ,'item' => 'Pear','supplier'=> 'BOB','usd'=> '10'));
$buy=array();
foreach ($array as $item){

    if($item['usd'] > 15){
        $buy[$item['supplier']]= $item['usd'];
    }

}
print_r($buy);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array ( [SAM] => 30 [TOM] => 20 )
```